# How to: database layout MySQL

Tags: mysql

let's say I have 5 values they are the person's interest should I make 5 separate columns for these values or is there another way.

```
     id | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5
row: 1  | sport  | movies | coding |  games |  food
```

- I feel that it's inefficient to make 5 separate columns for this but I don't know how to do this differently saw something about a (SET) data in MySQL but many are saying not to use it so IDK what to do.

**thanks and have a good day, stay safe**

> if I need to edit/change/clarify/provide more info. just comment on the post and I will do it :)

Comment: Is there any problem in using five seperate **rows** and assign them to the user through a relation table?

Comment: um this cant go into 5 separate rows cuz all this is in one row but ut separate columns, and no theres no problem with that i just believe there is a more appropriate way of doing it

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Comment: Using this in a single row with five colums looks pretty wrong to me, but that could also depend on your requirements

Comment: @NicoHaaseno YES, i know thats what my problem is i dont think it is supposed to be this way but #1 was the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I try to explain it in a few sentences. The problem here is of you make 5 columns, what if another person got 6, 7 or 10 hobbies? Thats not practical.
If you would simply make another row for each hobbie, the chance to write spelling errors while copying are high and you wont find it then after.

The better idea is it to make another table with the hobbies and then join it together again, the keyword is "normalisation".

What should you do now?
Make a unique Key Field for your Persons Table, and that Field you use in that other table for your Hobbies:

```
PersonID Name       Vorname 
1        SmapleName FirstName
2        Attenberg  David

PersonID Hobby
1  | sport 
1  | walking
1  | eating 
1  | movies 
1  | fish 
2  | walking
2  | eating
```

And then if you want to select all hobbies you just have to get your PersonID from the First table and then select all records from your new Table, the keyword here is INNER JOIN.

Comment: yes that's what I have I got a users table and a user_info table the users table has name profile and contact info the user_info is hobbies and other stuff but like you said i think i will have to split it 3 ways users , user_info , user_hobbies

Comment: This doesn't help with the spelling issue

Comment: yes i know i actually wanted to do it your way but tough there might be another way where i dont have to make so many table cuz i other stuff thats are similar to this but i guess its not bad to make more tables